# python yaml error on odoo11 stock module installation. yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!python'

Tags: python, odoo-11, pyyaml

I have setup a `odoo11` database and trying to install stock module but it will generate python yaml error.

Error logs:

```
2019-04-09 12:21:06,147 15820 INFO sicpa_db odoo.modules.loading: loading stock/views/stock_template.xml
2019-04-09 12:21:06,391 15820 INFO sicpa_db odoo.modules.loading: loading stock/views/procurement_views.xml
2019-04-09 12:21:06,546 15820 INFO sicpa_db odoo.modules.loading: loading stock/data/default_barcode_patterns.xml
2019-04-09 12:21:06,592 15820 INFO sicpa_db odoo.modules.loading: loading stock/data/stock_data.xml
2019-04-09 12:21:07,294 15820 INFO sicpa_db odoo.modules.loading: loading stock/data/stock_data.yml
2019-04-09 12:21:07,300 15820 WARNING sicpa_db odoo.modules.loading: Transient module states were reset
2019-04-09 12:21:07,336 15820 ERROR sicpa_db odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gajanan/others/erp/odoo11-git/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 85, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/gajanan/others/erp/odoo11-git/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 380, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/home/gajanan/others/erp/odoo11-git/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 274, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/home/gajanan/others/erp/odoo11-git/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 181, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/home/gajanan/others/erp/odoo11-git/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/home/gajanan/others/erp/odoo11-git/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 789, in convert_file
    convert_yaml_import(cr, module, fp, kind, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/home/gajanan/others/erp/odoo11-git/odoo/tools/yaml_import.py", line 854, in yaml_import
    yaml_interpreter.process(yaml_string)
  File "/home/gajanan/others/erp/odoo11-git/odoo/tools/yaml_import.py", line 794, in process
    for node in yaml.load(yaml_string):
  File "/home/gajanan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 114, in load
  File "/home/gajanan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 43, in get_single_data
  File "/home/gajanan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 52, in construct_document
  File "/home/gajanan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 404, in construct_yaml_map
  File "/home/gajanan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 210, in construct_mapping
  File "/home/gajanan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 131, in construct_mapping
  File "/home/gajanan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 92, in construct_object
  File "/home/gajanan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 420, in construct_undefined
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!python'
  in "<byte string>", line 2, column 3:
      !python {model: ir.model.data, i ... 
      ^
```

I am unable to install other apps too, please help.

Comment: Is there code to go with this ? Make sure you follow the official docs in setup? https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/install.html

Answer (score 3):

You're probably having problems because PyYAML has had some breaking changes and because the packages dependent on PyYAML have not been updated and/or have not been pinned to an older version of PyYAML.

What you should do is run `pip list` and see what version of PyYAML you have. If that version is >= 4.0, then run:

```
pip install -U pyyaml==3.13
```

PyYAML is not in the `requirements.txt` for odoo so you probably got the latest version PyYAML, which is not (no longer) compatible.